# AJAX way of handling filters in a Django based ecommerce application is not working upon copy pasting the url in new tab

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

So I ran into this problem two days back and still haven't got a proper solution. I would highly Appreciate any help in here.
Let me explain the scenario first, so the idea is I have one django based ecommerce site and I want to render the product showcase page through ajax call (without reloading) and same time also update the url as the selected filters for example (http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist?category=category_1).

I want to achieve similar to this site - [shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/travel?color=red&age=60s&mreleased=true&number_of_people=2).

My Scenario -

- http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist this page to showcase all the available products and also have the filters option and pagination.
- Now when I change the page or apply some filter I am e.g. http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist?category_slug=category_1 then it is working, but when I refresh the page it is not.. the reason behind this the way I am handling this ajax call in the backend.

  ```
  def customer_categories(request):
    # Get attributes from request url
    current_page = request.GET.get('page' ,'1')
    category_slug = request.GET.get('category_slug')
    sortby_filter = request.GET.get('sortby_filter')
    price_filter = request.GET.get('price_filter')
    search_query= request.GET.get('term')
    line_filter_min = request.GET.get('price_min')
    line_filter_max = request.GET.get('price_max')

    # Set limit and offset for queryset
    limit = REQUEST_PER_PAGE * int(current_page)
    offset = limit - REQUEST_PER_PAGE 
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    # products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)[offset:limit]  # limiting products based on current_page
    # products_count = Product.objects.filter(available=True).count()

    # Check product already in cartlist
    cartlist_check = []
    cart_item_count = cart_count(request)
    cart_items = cart_list(request)
    for cart in cart_items:
        cartlist_check.append(cart['product'].id)

    # Check product already in wishlist, only if user logged in
    wishlist_check =[]
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        wishlist_items_check = WishList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        for item in wishlist_items_check:
            wishlist_check.append(item.product_id)
        wishlist_count = wishlist_counts(request.user)
    else:
        wishlist_count = 0

    # If category_slug True
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug).\
            get_descendants(include_self=True)
    else:
        category = None

    time1 = time.time()
    # Filters for multiselect, retun products and products_count
    products,  products_count, search_list = attribute_filter(category=category,
                                                search_query=search_query,
                                                sortby_filter=sortby_filter,
                                                price_filter=price_filter,
                                                line_filter_min=line_filter_min,
                                                line_filter_max=line_filter_max,
                                                offset=offset,
                                                limit=limit)

    time2= time.time()
    print('Time Elapsed')
    print(time2-time1)
    if len(products) > 0:
        # adding one more page if the last page will contains less products
        total_pages = math.ceil(products_count / REQUEST_PER_PAGE )  

    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    wish_list_form = WishListForm()
    total_pages = math.ceil(products_count / REQUEST_PER_PAGE )  # adding one more page if the last page will contains less products
    if not current_page == '1' or category_slug:
        print('------------------------------')
        return render(request, 'customer/products/products_by_category.html',\
            {'products': products,
            'wishlist_item_check': wishlist_check,
            'cartlist_item_check': cartlist_check,
            'current_page': current_page,
            'total_products': products_count,
            'request_per_page': REQUEST_PER_PAGE,
            'total_pages':total_pages
            })

    else:
        return render(request, 'customer/home/customer_showcase.html',\
            {'products': products,
            'categories':categories,
            'cart_product_form': cart_product_form,
            'wish_list_form': wish_list_form,
            'wishlist_item_check': wishlist_check,
            'wishlist_count': wishlist_count,
            'cart':cart_items,
            'items_count':cart_item_count,
            'cartlist_item_check': cartlist_check,
            'current_page': current_page,
            'total_pages':total_pages,
            'total_products': products_count,
            'request_per_page': REQUEST_PER_PAGE,
            })
  ```
- Ajax part of the code is here

  ```
  $('.selected_subcategory').on('click', function () {
    send_data['selected_subcategory'] = $(this).attr('data-id');
    getPopularProductsData($(this).attr('data-id'));
    // getAPIData();

    var params = window.location.search;
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var old_url = path + params;
    var url = old_url;
    const state = {}
    const title = ''
    console.log('old urll', old_url)
    let new_url=''
    if(params){
      new_url = removeDuplicate(old_url)
    }

    console.log('new url', new_url)
    history.pushState(state, title, url)
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: old_url,
      data: {
        category_slug: send_data['selected_subcategory']
      },
      beforeSend: function () {
        $('#products').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Loading...</div>');
        // $('#spinner3').addClass('d-block');
      },
      success: function (result) {
        if (result['error']) {
          let message =
            '<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
            result['error'] +
            '  <a class="" href="http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist/" style="text-decoration: underline">click here</a>' +
            '</div>';
          $('#products').html(message);
        } else {

          document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = result;
        }

        const state = {}
        const title = ''
        const url = this.url
        history.pushState(state, title, url)
      },
      error: function (response) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: 200,
        });
        $('#products').html(
          '<div class="alert alert-danger">Something went wrong!!!</div>'
        );
        $('#list_data').hide();
        // $('#spinner3').addClass('d-none');
      },
    });
  });
  ```

My expectation is when I browse this http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist?page=2&category_slug=category_1 link it would render the same which matches with the query params, but in a ajax way.

Sorry for the long explanation. Hope my point is clear through this explanation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here in your Django part, you are returning two different HTML outputs when there is `category_slug` and not.

If there is `category_slug` in your request you returning `'customer/products/products_by_category.html'`

But when there is no category slug you are returning `'customer/home/customer_showcase.html'`.

Both HTML files are different in their layout. The first one doesn't provide the header or container elements. This is the central problem of your issue.

**You can Fix this issue by**

You can put a special parameter in ajax api call, by which Django can realize that is is an api call, this time it returns `products_by_category.html`.
And you want to make unique all other returns to `customer_showcase.html`, but if there is a category filter you can pass filtered content to the products list. If category_slug is None or empty you can pass all products without the filter to the same HTML file.

You can also differentiate ajax api call by making it a POST request and all other web requests remains GET requests. So you can easily identify the traffic.

Here is the changes in Django:

```
    if request.method == "POST"::
      print('------------------------------')
      return render(request, 'customer/products/products_by_category.html',\
          {'products': products,
          'wishlist_item_check': wishlist_check,
          'cartlist_item_check': cartlist_check,
          'current_page': current_page,
          'total_products': products_count,
          'request_per_page': REQUEST_PER_PAGE,
          'total_pages':total_pages
          })
    else:
      return render(request, 'customer/home/customer_showcase.html',\
          {'products': products,
          'categories':categories,
          'cart_product_form': cart_product_form,
          'wish_list_form': wish_list_form,
          'wishlist_item_check': wishlist_check,
          'wishlist_count': wishlist_count,
          'cart':cart_items,
          'items_count':cart_item_count,
          'cartlist_item_check': cartlist_check,
          'current_page': current_page,
          'total_pages':total_pages,
          'total_products': products_count,
          'request_per_page': REQUEST_PER_PAGE,
          })
```

And make your ajax call to "POST", change in your front end code: `method: 'POST'`,
Don't forget to add slash(/) at the end of url when you change to POST.

Comment: I got your point but if I do so then how do I resolve the following problems - How do I make use of this url  http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist?page=2&category_slug=category_1 .. Moreover you can see the expected outcome following this link https://www.shutterstock.com/search/travel?color=red&age=60s&mreleased=true&number_of_people=2 .. And I know the reason behind getting two different outputs for the same api call (I've mentioned it in the first bullet point). My question is how to handle both things at same call...like with query params and without any.

Comment: When you apply the above fix, you will get the same result for [with category_slug](http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist?page=2&category_slug=category_1) as you get in [home](http://vps.vanijyam.com:8000/customerlist).

Comment: I am not making any post request here... and I don't want to make any too..

Comment: Then you can filter your products listing in Django by looking for your parameters. First you can take all of your products into a variable and filter this if your GET request have 'category_slug'. Then pass the products to templates products as you do in your code.

Comment: I tried this too... but not working.. can you bit more descriptive and show some code. I think my approach is not in the right way... you can check the link I mentioned above and suggest your thought... go to showcase and change page number and then do a refresh

Comment: Did you change your backend (Django) as my suggestion? If yes then you want to add some more scripts to your frontend. That script will load after the document is ready. This script will check for slugs in the URL, and evaluates them and arranges page number, active category and other details based on current url.